# how to avoid "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am working with webpack to setup a react project. but after running command below

```
npm start
```

I have got following error in terminal

```
× ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry['main'] should not contain the item '—' twice.
   -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
```

here is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')},
    module:{
        rules:[{
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
    plugins:[
        new HWP(
           {template: path.join(__dirname,'/src/index.html')}
        )
    ]
}
```

And below is the code for package.json

```
{
  "name": "aragon-connect-1.1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server — mode development — open — hot",
    "build": "webpack — mode production"
  },
  "author": "Author Name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Can anyone let me know about where I am getting wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if it's a formatting problem, but I find this very strange: `— mode development`. It should be `--mode development`, with two hyphens not followed by space. Same with the other parameters in `start` and `build`.

Comment: thanks for your reply But it does not help in my case

Answer (score 4):

Can you try with this scripts?

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Also, make sure webpack config is called `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the options format you're using in scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server — mode development — open — hot",
    "build": "webpack — mode production"
  },
```

Options passed in running webpack build should be used like `--mode`, but you've used `-` above.

Answer (score 0):

`entry` assumes to have relative path not absolute path.

```
entry: {  main: "./src/index.js" },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that in your package.json file change the "main" property

```
{
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
}
```